# Where to declare extensions in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have declared an extensions of Double at the end of ContentView. But it shows error "Initializeer 'init(_:) requires that 'Double' conform to 'StringProtocol'".

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var demo: Double = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $demo, from: 0.0, through: 100.0, by: 0.01)
                .padding()
            Text(demo.roundTo(places: 5))
       }
    }
}
extension Double {
    public func roundTo(places: Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Comment: code is required

Comment: Added code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text view needs a string. Change your Text view to:

```swift
Text("\(demo.roundTo(places: 5))")
```